# Is there an easy way to get .NET MemoryCache statistics?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm interested in possible optimizations based on how of a hit rate a key has compared to other keys.

Does .NET natively expose any cache statistics such as number of times a key has been hit? Any helper library recommendations are also appreciated.